# How do I get a popup validation message from a page using selenium Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, user-interface, testing

How do I get the popup validation message "Please tick this box if you want to continue" using Selenium Python in the photo?

```html
<input oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please tick this box if you want to proceed')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" class="form-check-input checkbox-switch-md" type="checkbox" id="registerTermsCheckboxId" required="">
```

[image]

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qchv6.png)

Comment: Hi, @Rst Ozyrt I have updated your question to be a bit more descriptive. I suggest you also add what have you tried so far and which Selenium web driver are you currently using. Also is it Django you are using?

Comment: Can you share the link to the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem, where I was able to extract the text in the validation message with the following JavaScriptExecutor code:

```
message_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, Locators.acceptCheckButton_xpath)
accept_button_message = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].validationMessage", message_element)
print("Message : ", accept_button_message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, I hope this will solve your issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


toolTip = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'registerTermsCheckboxId')))
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(toolTip)
txt = hov.perform()
tooltipText = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'registerTermsCheckboxId'))).text
print(tooltipText)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the message (text) is not received with this code.

Comment: Try to change the locator, or can you share link of the webpage